# Gallery doesn't working properly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a pictures gallery that I was calling with a javascript function and it worked fine. Now I'm going to make it in PHP so the user can change and delete some images. I decided to still do it in javascript and just pass the parameter in PHP. The function takes the image name as a parameter, and I'm passing it in php in my `window.onload` on the page.

The problem:

Each gallery has 4 pictures. I should have 3 galleries with 4 different pictures each, instead, I'm getting 4 galleries with repeated images in each one. The php is executing the JS function 4 times with the same parameter, because I have 4 values in my table.

How could I make it right?

Here's the codes:

```
function galerias(query){
    var galeria = new Array();

        var imgs = document.querySelector("#gallery");
        var x = 1;

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = query;
        }


        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+query+"'class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a class='row' href='pics.html?gal="+x+"'><div class='twelve columns link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
        x++;

}

//this is in my window.onload, so it loads the galleries with the page:

    <?php
        foreach($galeria_1 as $result){
            echo'galerias("'.$result['nome'].'");';
        }
    ?>

//this is in my separate file that make the DB functions:
    function consultarDados($query){
        $dbResult = array();
        $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
        mysql_select_db($this->banco, $conexao);
        $rs = mysql_query($query, $conexao);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
                array_push($dbResult, $rows);
            }
        return $dbResult;
        mysql_close($conexao);
    }

//and this is how i call it in my galleries page:
<?php 
    include 'connectDB.php';
    $conexao = new connectDb();
    $galeria_1= $conexao->consultarDados('select * from portfolio where gal= 1 and theme= 1');
?>
```

Comment: Did you confirm `$result` is different in each of your iterations of your PHP loop?

Comment: @SethMcClaine does jsFiddle also takes PHP lines ?

Comment: Sorry.... I was concentrating on the js and wasn't thinking about the php :-P

Comment: Did you confirm $result is different in each of your iterations of your PHP loop?

Comment: @SethMcClaine Yes ! For sure !